# What not to add within a using statement?

Tags: c#, vb.net, using-statement

I face this scenario multiple times and not quit sure what is the best practice:

**Option 1**:

```
SomeType x = null;
using (var db = new DbEntities())
       {
        x = db.GetInfo();
       }
DoSomethingWith(x);
```

**Option 2**:

```
using (var db = new DbEntities())
       {
       var x = db.GetInfo();
       DoSomethingWith(x);
       }
```

Obviously op2 is shorter and could even be condensed further but does that make it the best practice when the using statement is part of the equation?

And beyond this concrete example, what in general ***not*** to add within a using statement?

Comment: I prefer the first snippet.

Comment: It's not about preferring one or the other, it's about what the code does, in particular the `DoSomethingWith` method. But almost always you would likely use the first option.

Comment: Not sure this is opinion based. If `x` is lazy evaluated option 1 (while otherwise more performant) will cause some major issues.

Comment: @itsme86, the first snippet is actually what pushed me to ask the question because that is what I do, yet I am left not satisfied with declaring a loose variable.

Comment: Your outlook is wrong. At the end of a `using`, a resource is deterministically disposed. That's the important bit. You *usually* want to dispose resources at the earliest possible convenience, which is why you want to keep the block (use of the resource) as short as possible. But that does not translate into a list of rules for what not to add. To paraphrase Einstein, a `using` block should be as short as possible, but no shorter.

Comment: You should put all the code that requires the object in the `using` to be active and not disposed in the `using` block.  We cannot determine what that is without knowing more about your methods.

Comment: @juharr in the real method all I do is to send the x object to another View using MessengerLight. However, in many other scenarios, the DoSomething method could be more complicated and hence takes longer to complete.

Comment: @usefulBee: the real issue is whether or not the `db` object will be kept alive and needed after the `using` has disposed it. If `db.GetInfo()` returns a deferred LINQ query on an open connection that isn't actually executed until someone invokes a method or property on `x`, then the first alternative is not an alternative but a (relatively common) programming error. Otherwise, it's fine (but you'll want to remove the `= null` initialization, as it masks errors with forgetting to assign it).

Comment: @usefulBee Likely the fist is fine and better options, but if `x` is a EF `Entity` using it can result in deffered queries that require the original context to still exist and thus would need to be inside of the `using`.  Personally I avoid returning entities in the first place to avoid that type of thing and instead hydrate a DTO with the exact data I need which is safe to leave this `using` scope.

Answer (score 0):

If the DoSomethingWith(x) only works inside the using statement, then pick Option 2, otherwise Option 1. If you're wondering whether there is any optimization to gain from either choice, correct me if I am wrong but I don't see why there would be.